# Data from List<Memo> doesn't show in datagridview

Tags: c#, forms

I have a list made by user input which is bound to a datasource class, I also have a datagridview where the data is supposed to be put into the datagrid.

```
        private void ViewMemo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dgvMemo.DataSource = Datasources.memorecorders;
    }
```

this is the AddMemo class

```
        private void btAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int SerialId;
        SerialId = int.Parse(txtSerialId.Text);

        decimal price;
        price = decimal.Parse(txtPrijs.Text);


        MemoRecorder m1 = new MemoRecorder(SerialId);
        m1.make = txtMerk.Text;
        m1.model = txtModel.Text;
        m1.priceExBtw = price;
        m1.creationDate = dtProductie.Value;

        foreach (MemoCartridgeType mem in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MemoCartridgeType)))
        {
            if (cbCartridge.SelectedValue.ToString() == mem.ToString())
            {
                m1.maxCartridgeType = mem;

            }
        }

        Datasources.memorecorders.Add(m1);

        MessageBox.Show("uitkomst: Merk: " + m1.make + "model: " + m1.model +  " ,prijs Ex btw:  "+  m1.priceExBtw +  " ,CartridgeType:  "+ m1.maxCartridgeType
            + " ,Creatie Datum: " + m1.creationDate);

        txtMerk.Text = String.Empty;
        txtModel.Text = String.Empty;
        txtPrijs.Text = String.Empty;
    }
```

but when I view the datagridview the data is not in there, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
Datasources.memorecorders.Add(m1);
dgvMemo.DataSource = Datasources.memorecorders;
 MessageBox.Show("uitkomst: Merk: " + m1.make + "model: " + m1.model +  " ,prijs Ex btw:  "+  m1.priceExBtw +  " ,CartridgeType:  "+ m1.maxCartridgeType
            + " ,Creatie Datum: " + m1.creationDate);
```

Comment: thanks for the comment! But this doesn't work, the dvgMemo is located in another class so I can't access it in the AddMemo class...